# Detect whether a webpage is being viewed inside an iOS or Android webview?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, detect

I'm using Mobile Detect (http://mobiledetect.net/) to check which browser is being used for my webpage, but I'm struggling to get the correct check for whether a page is being viewed inside an iOS or Android webview.

The following options are available, but I just can't get it working. Is it possible?

```
isSafari()
isioS()
isAndroid()
isAndroidOS()
isChrome()
```

etc.. (Full list at http://demo.mobiledetect.net/)

Has anybody succesfully done this?  My reason behind wanting to do this is that I have a banner on my website that tells users to download the iOS or Android app. Now this bit works fine.

However in the app itself, there is a webview that allows the user to browse the site too, and in this case I wouldn't want the banner to appear because they are already using the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For this question

> However in the app itself, there is a webview that allows the user to browse the site too, and in this case I wouldn't want the banner to appear because they are already using the app.

You need to embed one GET variable along with your website URL. For example

```
http://www.example.com?isInsideApp=true
```

Then at server side get the GET string and check whether it is `true` OR something else. If it is `true` then don't show ads.

Comment: This is something we're going to consider if we can't get a simple solution to the above.

Comment: As simple as it gets!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the user agent on server side?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check() {
            if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
                userAgent = 'iOS';
            } else if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {
                userAgent = 'Android';
            }
         }
    </script>
```

Comment: This wouldn't differentiate between a user browsing the website on Safari or inside the app itself though. Right?

Comment: hmm you are right this does not diferentiate the browsers, for that adding an extra param to the link would suffice i think.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getMobileOS() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

    if (/windows phone/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Windows";
    }

    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return "Android";
    }


    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return "iOS";
    }

    return "unknown";
}
```